# Pip install failure on Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip

When I try to install my project from the requirements.txt file, I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` and it fails on my pandas dependency. I am not exactly sure why does anyone have any advice?

pip version:

```
pip 20.0.2 from c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.5)
```

requirements.txt:

```
numpy==1.18.2
 pandas==1.0.3
 python-dateutil==2.8.1
 pytz==2019.3
 six==1.14.0
```

Error:

```
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==1.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 0.1, 0.2b0, 0.2b1, 0.2, 0.3.0b0, 0.3.0b2, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0rc1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0rc1, 0.8.0rc2, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0rc1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0rc1, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0rc1, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0, 0.23.0rc2, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.23.3, 0.23.4, 0.24.0rc1, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

Comment: Are you using the newest version of `pip`?

Comment: yes I ran the upgrade before running pip install

Comment: share the output of `pip --version`

Comment: `pip 20.0.2 from c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.5)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like that happened to me in the past. I solved it by uninstalling pandas then reinstalling it again. Perhaps you installed pandas long time ago so your version of out of date.

Comment: Whoever votes down a post should indicate the reason!

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas` 1.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.0.0/) requires Python 3.6+. The last version that supports Python 3.5 is [0.25.3](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/0.25.3/). Either use the version or upgrade to Python 3.6+ (3.6, 3.7 or 3.8).